# Get original definition of redefined function

Tags: javascript

I am writing a bookmarklet which performs some function on a page. As part of this function I need to use `getElementsByClassName`. However, during testing I found that several websites have redefined `getElementsByClassName` to a custom method. Presumably this was done in order to support `getElementsByClassName` in all browsers.

The implementation of custom `getElementsByClassName` is a bit sloppy and fails for several of my use cases. Is there any way I could get the original definition of `getElementsByClassName`?

In the chrome javascript console: `getElementsByClassName` points to a native function. Is there a way to access this native function, now that `getElementsByClassName` has been redefined?

Comment: You can cache it beforehand, or change those scripts to add support only when native support doesn't exist (most should do this anyway), but once it's overridden, you can't get it back.

Comment: @davin Unfortunately, I do not own/control the pages or their scripts.

Comment: Like I said, I am writing a bookmarklet, not a script that's embedded in the page. So I cannot modify the function which redines getElementsByClassName, which is why I am looking for some other way of accessing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a solution, but it is not robust. See the disclaimer at the bottom.

If you open a new window you will have access to its unmodified methods. I can think of two ways to open a new window: using `window.open`, and in an iframe. The iframe is less obtrusive because it won't distract the user by opening new browser windows or triggering pop-up blockers.

```
// Runs fn with a clean window reference
function getCleanReferences(fn) {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    var newWindow = iframe.contentWindow;
    iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
    return fn(newWindow);
}
```

Some browsers won't like removing the iframe. If you want this to work in Safari or Firefox, delete the removeChild line. Next, you will want to get the getElementsByClassName method from the new window.

```
var nativeGetElementsByClassName = getCleanReferences(function(newWindow) {
    var getElementsByClassName = newWindow.document.getElementsByClassName;
    return function(className) {
        return getElementsByClassName.call(window.document, className);
    };
});
```

This is pretty much cross-browser, except that IE doesn't like getElementsByClassName in quirks mode or before version 9 (which you have little control over in a bookmarklet). Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/theazureshadow/vdqYG/

And if you're curious about my experiments with importing other methods, take a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/theazureshadow/ccFG3/

**DISCLAIMER:** Using methods from other windows in the context of the current one is dangerous, undefined territory. If you choose to use this fragile approach, make sure you test for cross-browser compatibility. My tests showed major differences in how different browsers treat this approach. You should not use this on a production site, but it might be okay for a personal bookmarklet. It is probably much safer to just include your own version of whatever method you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is not possible. This is why monkeypatching is bad. One should never redefine host objects.

Answer (score 1):

I guess some sites use prototype. The DOM's [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) returns a `NodeList` whereas Prototype's [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/getElementsByClassName) returns an `Array` because `NodeList`s cannot be created by a JS-Scripts.

In Firefox you could use

```
var node = document;
Components.lookupMethod(node, 'getElementsByClassName').call(node, /* className */);
```

to get the original method. Maybe Google Chrome implements something similar otherwise you'll be out of luck. I couldn't find anything (2 min googling).

In this case you can use something like this:

```
function getElementsByClassName(node, className) {
    var rv = new Array();
    var nodeList = node.getElementsByTagName('*');
    className = className.replace(/([\.\\\\\+\*\?\[\^\]\$\(\)\{\}\=\!\<\>\|\:\-])/, '\\$1');
    var regex = new RegExp('(?:^|[\\n\\r ])' + className + '(?:[\\n\\r ]|$)');
    for(var length = nodeList.length, i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        if(regex.test(nodeList[ i ].className)) {
            rv.push(nodeList[ i ]);
        }
    }
    return rv;
}
```

If Google Chrome implements `node.classList` you can use the following function which doesn't use a creepy regex:

```
function getElementsByClassName(node, className) {
    var rv = new Array();
    var nodeList = node.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for(var length = nodeList.length, i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        if(nodeList[ i ].classList.contains(className)) {
            rv.push(nodeList[ i ]);
        }
    }
    return rv;
}
```

This function iterates over all elements inside the given node. It returns an Array like Prototype and share the same drawback: Arrays aren't "live" like `NodeList`s.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to your second solution. The third solution doesn't really work for me because I need a NodeList. Currently trying to find if there is a webkit equivalent method for Firefox's lookupMethod. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the custom method is defined. You can access the method as `Element.prototype.getElementsByClassName` but if the page overwrites this prototype method, I don't think there is a way to get it back.