# Return the default value to a predefined javascript object

Tags: javascript

How can you restore the default value of a predefined JavaScript object or function (like the object `window.console`, or the function `document.getElementById`) once it has been changed?

Comment: You can [edit] your question. Duplicate or at least related: [Get original definition of redefined function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9194025/218196)

Comment: If it's only about `console`: [“Un-redefining” Google Chrome's console Object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6131651/218196) (although you can apply the same technique to other things and it's basically the same as the first link does).

Comment: @FelixKling And what if the document.createElement function is overwritten too? And HTMLIFrameElement.prototype? And/Or document.appendChild function?

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @FelixKling solves the question I formuled. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9194025/218196) is an example.
Thank you, @FelixKling.
On the other hand, I have formuled another question, more concise, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22986880/return-default-value-to-predefined-javascript-objects-in-concrete-circumstances)