# Return default value to predefined javascript objects in concrete circumstances

Tags: javascript, dom, client-side

Some days ago, I asked a question , that was:

> How could anyone return the default value to a predefined JavaScript
>   object or function (like the object window.console, or the
>   object-function document.getElementById) once it has been changed?

Posted here: 
[Return the default value to a predefined javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22926255/return-the-default-value-to-a-predefined-javascript-object)

The solution wasn't enough, because the possibility to return the default value was based on creating an iframe object and insert it to the current DOM. But, we also have the possibility to override the functions that let the client-side insert nodes into the DOM, like document.appendChild, document.insertBefore, ... For example, the concrete circunstances that I would like to know if it is possible to return the default value to a predefeined javascript object, like "console", "window", or anyone, are these:

```
HTMLdocument.prototype.createElement = undefined;
HTMLdocument.prototype.createAttribute = undefined;
HTMLdocument.prototype.createComment = undefined;
HTMLdocument.prototype.createDocumentFragment = undefined;
HTMLdocument.prototype.createElement = undefined;
HTMLdocument.prototype.createTextNode = undefined;
Node.prototype.appendChild = undefined;
Node.prototype.cloneNode = undefined;
Node.prototype.insertBefore = undefined;
Node.prototype.removeChild = undefined;
Node.prototype.replaceChild = undefined;
```

I hope that now the question is concise enough. **The final question I would really like to solve is: is there any code-context in which it is impossible to return the default value to a predefined javascript object like console, for example?** All my questions go around this final one. Thank you!

Comment: Nobody? I think this is important an important issue, because a lot of important web pages like Facebook, Google or Youtube don't implement this type of security (for logical reasons, in the other hand, and I mean AJAX). But excluding AJAX based web applications, this kind of security measure would annoy a lot to the XSS searchers... and I am not an expert at all!

Comment: And please, correct me if I'm wrong, I just want to learn!